# SonarLint, Array of String: Declare this local variable with "var" instead = error

Tags: java, var, sonarlint

With `Java 11`, for this code:

```java
String[] arrayString = {"foo", "bar"};
```

`SonarLint` say `Declare this local variable with "var" instead.`

So, I have tried:

```java
var arrayString = {"foo", "bar"};
// or
var[] arrayString = {"foo", "bar"};
```

But now I get these errors:

- `Array initializer needs an explicit target-type`
- `'var' is not allowed as an element type of an array`

How can I declare correctly array variables or attributes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
var arrayString = new String[]{"foo", "bar"};
```

Comment: Lol. "Use `var` so you don't have to declare the type!", they said.